# configuration in Android 4.0 emulator for calling webservice

Tags: android, web-services

i am try to call webservice using Android.I have used httpclient as well as SOAP.But in each case i am not getting any response.Also the exception is NULL.

using httpclient this line is not executing:

```
responsePOST = client.execute(post);
```

So,do i need to configure any properties in my android emulator to call webservices?Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you given permission in the manifest for Internet access
android.permission.INTERNET

-Rajdeep